# Assertion message in switch case do not display

Tags: java, switch-statement, assertion

Assertion message in switch case do not display. 
It should output the given error message whenever a user inputs < 0 or >6.
My assertion is in the default part and the message wont display. what's wrong with my code?

```
import java.util.*;
public class DeckOfCards extends Inputs{
//objects
//sets
//int

public DeckOfCards(){
    //some initialization
}

public void setValtyp(String val){
    this.valtyp = valtyp;
}

public String getValtyp(){
    return this.valtyp;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    int exit = 0;
    do{
        try{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int option;
            int option2;
            String yesno;
            int back = 0;
            String val;
            String typ;
            System.out.println("Deck of Cards");
            System.out.println("[1]Add");
            System.out.println("[2]Delete");
            System.out.println("[3]Display");
            System.out.println("[4]Search");
            System.out.println("[5]Count");
            System.out.println("[6]Exit");
            System.out.print("Option: ");
            option = input.nextInt();

            switch(option){
                case 1:
                   //codes
                   break;
                case 2:
                    //codes
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //codes
                    break;
                case 4:
                   //codes
                   break;
                case 5:
                    do{
                        try{
                            System.out.println("\nDeck of Cards");
                            System.out.println("[1]Heart");
                            System.out.println("[2]Diamond");
                            System.out.println("[3]Spade");
                            System.out.println("[4]Clover");
                            System.out.println("[5]All");
                            System.out.println("[6]Back");
                            System.out.print("Option: ");
                            option2 = input.nextInt();

                            switch(option2){
                                case 1: 
                                    System.out.println("\nHearts: "+kerds.heart.size());
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    System.out.println("\nDiamond: "+kerds.diamond.size());
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    System.out.println("\nSpade: "+kerds.spade.size());
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    System.out.println("\nClover: "+kerds.clover.size());
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                    int totalsize;
                                    totalsize = kerds.heart.size() + kerds.diamond.size() + kerds.spade.size() + kerds.clover.size();
                                    System.out.println("\nAll: "+totalsize);
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    System.out.println("");
                                    back++;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    assert false : "Option is out of range. Please try again.\n";
                                    back++;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        catch(InputMismatchException e){
                            System.out.println("Invalid Option! Please try again.\n");
                            back++;
                        }
                    }while(back!=1);
                    break;        
                case 6:
                    exit++;
                    break;
                default:
                    assert false : "Option is out of range. Please try again.\n";
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid Option! Please try again.\n");
        }
    }while(exit!=1);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you enabled assertions? `java -ea`

Comment: how can i enable assertions?

Comment: as above, use the `-ea` argument. If you are using Eclipse, go to Run Configurations, select the run config, Arguments tab, and put `-ea` in the VM Arguments box.

Comment: I searched the net on how to do it and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `back++`from

```
      default:
              assert false : "Option is out of range. Please try again.\n";
              back++;
              break;
```

You break out of the loop when user types in the wrong value, because `back == 1` at that point and your `do-while` loop ends and your first `do-while` loop executes again, and I don't think that is what you wanted to do, rather run the second loop again at wrong input

Comment: yeah i didnt noticed that. Thanks :)